# Get error when I try to retrieve graph token from Microsoft online graph url

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, postman, bearer-token

I am trying to retrieve the token for Microsoft graph online URL the request is successful when I run it in Postman.
Here is the link I have used in Postman: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantID%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) and I am sending all the keys inside the form-data like this
[image: form data being sent in Postmant].

When I perform the same operation using Typescript using the following code:

```
    const graphTokenFormData = new FormData();
    graphTokenFormData.append("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
    graphTokenFormData.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    graphTokenFormData.append("client_id", client_id);
    graphTokenFormData.append("client_secret", client_secret);
    
    const graphTokenResponse = await fetch(
        graphTokenUrl, {
        method: "post",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        body: graphTokenFormData
    }).catch((reason) => {
        console.log(
            " Failed to fetch graph token from       
            https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            reason
        );
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
   graphBearerToken {
   error: 'invalid_request',
   error_description: "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter:  
    **'grant_type'**.\r\n" +
    'Trace ID: 9403fb3b-9f68-484b-9e78-d80d962f6800\r\n' +
    'Correlation ID: e961d5e7-33ef-452b-9273-0d02dcb4938c\r\n' +
    'Timestamp: 2023-10-16 12:58:54Z',
```

I tried to tweak it in various ways but I am not sure how to make the request to succeed.

Comment: I think the error you are facing might be the way you are setting the "Content-Type" header.  It should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` rather than `multipart/form-data`. Use `URLSearchParams` to create the form data.

Comment: Have you tried updating the content-header. Try to change graphTokenFormData.append to set. Change the append calls to set calls instead to set the values directly to the FormData object and retry your scenario